# Set the surface view border

Tags: android, view, camera, preview, surface

i am trying to add border to surface view but edges of surface view are overlapping the frame border in android.

how to hide surface view edges with frame layout(parent layout for surface view) border.

i have given the border background to frame layout and tried to hide the surface view edges.

please suggest the option to implement the approach.

[image showing the border is gettting hide by camera preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni31A.png)